# How to override Computer Not Reachable in scom?

Tags: scom

I'm trying to override monitor Computer Not Reachable to my group and Management pack, to alert me if connection is fail, but there is no anything when connection is break. Can anyone help me? Is it possible to override Computer Not Reachable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "Computer Not Reachable" pseudo-monitor triggers an alert when SCOM cannot ping a monitored computer. So, it has nothing in common with broken connection between a SCOM agent and a SCOM Management group. **NB!** Ping test only starts in response of communication failure (see further), it does not run continuously.

On the other hand, the "Health Service Heartbeat Failure" pseudo-monitor is exactly what you are looking for: it alerts when a SCOM Agent stops reporting back to its Management Group.

I said "pseudo-monitor" because they both are not real unit monitors, but fake roll-up monitors, which have no down-laying monitors -- so have nothing to roll up, but set programmatically instead.

Cheers

Max

Comment: How do you mean 'programmatically instead'? I need to create my own unit monitor or Aggregate roll-up monitor or what?

Thank you, 
Dragan

Comment: Literally, you don't need to override "Computer Not Reachable". Just use "Health Service Heartbeat Failure" for your purposes -- this is the monitor, which (as you wished): "to alert me if connection is fail".